# Flagging guidance for answers

Tags: discussion, answers, flagging

What is the appropriate usage of flagging for problem answers?

In general, flags are for things that are not appropriate as an answer post on that question. If it at least attempts to even partially address what the question asks, the appropriate action is probably not a flag. So let's get that out of the way first.

1. If it is **a wrong answer or a poor answer:**

   downvote and/or comment. (no flag)
2. If it is an answer but suffers from a **fixable problem** (e.g., formatting, grammar, etc.):

   Fix it if you can (edit), or comment. (no flag)
3. If it is **unclear or ambiguous, or a partial answer:**

   Explain the issue in a comment; offer constructive suggestions if you can. (no flag)
4. If the post **looks like a real answer but doesn't actually answer what was asked:**

   Before flagging, consider whether it might be an alternative solution, or frame challenge, that is missing wording to orient the reader. If that could be the case, comment or propose a clarifying edit. If it looks like the author misread or misunderstood the question, comment and give the author the opportunity to address it.

Note for #3 and #4: voting is, of course, allowed, as on any post. Keep in mind that the purpose of voting is to sort competing posts by their value. If an answer has an issue that the author may be fixing as a result of it being pointed out, consider delaying a downvote to give the author a chance to get the post into final form. If you do downvote immediately and then the author fixes the problem, please reassess your vote.

Also, if a new contributor makes a posting mistake, consider making it a learning opportunity and a positive site experience by providing constructive guidance in a comment rather than an immediate downvote. If you really think a downvote is appropriate and someone else has already provided that "guidance", weigh the value of piling on another downvote.

### If the post is not an attempt to answer that question, what's the appropriate flag to use?

It can be helpful to assess it in this sequence:

1. If it is **spam, rude, or abusive (including trolling):**

   Flag as **Spam** or **Rude/Abusive**.
2. If it is **unfixable noise** (e.g., incomprehensible, or unfocused rambling no more than vaguely related to the question), and serves no potentially useful purpose on the platform:

   Flag as **Very low quality**.
3. If it does not attempt to answer what was asked, but **might be appropriate as something other than an answer to that question** (e.g., a comment, an edit, an answer to some other question, or a new question):

   Flag as **Not an answer**.
4. If it has a problem that a moderator should handle and **doesn't neatly fit the standard flag definitions, or would benefit from explanation:**

   Use a custom flag (**in need of moderator intervention**), and describe the issue in the text box.